# LokiJS not allowing Json data to insert

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects, visual-studio-cordova

Hi i am using cordova/angularjs/lokijs while inserting records in db in json format it is showing typeerror("Document needs to be an object") but in case of simple array its working fine.I need to store as JSON as requirement.
Any help guys
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the `insert` code of LokiJS:

```
      var docs = Array.isArray(doc) ? doc : [doc];
      var results = [];
      docs.forEach(function (d) {
        if (typeof d !== 'object') {
          throw new TypeError('Document needs to be an object');
        }
```

where `doc` is the original object passed to the `insert` method, if `doc` is not an object LokiJS will throw an error. Make sure the argument you are passing to insert is a JS object, a `typeof` statement should confirm that.